# PHP wiki markup parser

Tags: php, parsing, wiki, markup

I've been told that writing a wiki markup parser in PHP that relies on regex and preg functions is a bad idea. But I don't know why.

So what's the best way to go about writing a wiki markup parser in PHP? This is more an academic 'project' than anything else, so the whole point is to write it myself.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Not knowing the reasoning for the cited advise it's difficult to assess its merits. Pretty much all contemporary wiki parsers are based on regular expressions however. Having implemented both a regex formatter and a state machine parser, I can only tell you that the regex approach is simpler, usually speedier and likely easier to maintain.

Comment: Using regex is a bad idea for the same reason you can't parse HTML like this: every component/template has a different inner syntax, and you can nest and combine then. Like HTML, the 'best' way is to 'stream parse' it, byte-by-byte, opening and closing components/templates along the stream. Very hard to do right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've been told that because "wiki languages" are *ill defined* to say the least.
The really bad part is *"trying to parse"* them, not *"using php and regexps"*.

In fact I believe they are **actually processed with regexps** *(straight into html, without passing from an intermediate abstract syntax tree representation)* in softwares like **mediawiki**. And AFAIK actual parsing without regexps is quite inefficient in PHP. (unless you're using a specific compiled PHP module for parsing)

Be aware that those softwares also have *a number of syntax features that can be activated on demand*, and that might prove hard to write efficiently.

Only real trouble? You have to use a lot of escapes to parse chars like `[` and `]`, it's easy to get confused when you use many backslashes with `preg_match()` and php. Apart from that, a simple `preg_match_all('#\\[\\[(.*?)\\]\\]#',$data,$matches,PREG_SET_ORDER);` should get you up and running.

*(unless I got confused by too many levels of backslashing, that is)* :)

Comment: Don't forget about nestable `{{` templates, and nestable `{|` templates.

Answer (score 2):

Probably the issue is that you have to run your regular expressions one at a time each across the entire contents of the wiki page, and that takes a lot of processing time.  A simple solution is to use some sort  of delimiter for tags, such as `[[`, and you process the text sequentially from beginning to end.  Each time you find a tag, you search for the end tag `]]`.

Next, you process the contents in between with whatever rules you have defined.  This can be accomplished using simple string indexing and replace operations, and doesn't require processing the entire string many times, but instead by passing through the entire string just once.

Comment: Finding the end tag is tricky, because you can nest `[[` templates in `{{` templates in `{|` templates. And those inside themselves. Etc.